# How to Send Message AWS S3 SNS to any phone number without Sandbox?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I create snd message using sns and its only send for phone number that verified. (Sandbox). how to make it without sandbox.

```
// Create promise and SNS service object

function sendSMS(params) {
  var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31' })
    .publish(params)
    .promise()
  // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
  publishTextPromise
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log('MessageID is ' + data.MessageId)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err, err.stack)
    })
}

sendSMS(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

From AWS Docs:

> Moving your AWS account out of the SMS sandbox requires that you first add, verify, and test destination phone numbers. Then, you must create a case with AWS Support.

For details, please see [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox-moving-to-production.html)

Comment: I've been exit from sandbox.  but 

`The SMS message to 62xxxx is accepted. For delivery status, check the delivery log.
Message "ID": 6ac05b29-68aa-54e3-a4b8-02b4036073fb
Request "ID": 5dd91f33-0850-50a7-ae25-46ae639af7bf`

But Receiver not get any messages...

Comment: You can follow the documentation here to receive logs for SMS deliveries: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html